# Why do I have SELinux problems after creating a logical volume (LVM)?

Tags: postfix, lvm, selinux

The default postfix queue directory om RHEL 7.3 is /var/spool/postfix. The permissions are 755, owner root, group root and SELinux context system_u:object_r:postfix_spool_t:s0.

I can remove all the directories and files in this directory. After a "systemctl restart postfix" the directories/files are recreated.

Then I mounted a logical volume on /var/spool/postfix, with the same permissions, owner, group and SELinux context. After "systemctl restart postfix" I got all kind of SELinux problems. So why is there a difference?
And what is a proper way to fix this?

At the moment I have this custom SELinux module, which is still incomplete:

```
  module postfix_queue 1.0;

  require {
    type postfix_master_t;
    type postfix_spool_t;
    type postfix_pickup_t;
    class capability { fowner fsetid };
    class fifo_file { create open read write unlink getattr setattr };
    class sock_file { create getattr setattr };
  }

  #============= postfix_master_t ==============
  allow postfix_master_t self:capability { fowner fsetid };
  allow postfix_master_t postfix_spool_t:fifo_file { create open read write unlink getattr setattr };
  allow postfix_master_t postfix_spool_t:sock_file { create getattr setattr };
  allow postfix_pickup_t postfix_spool_t:fifo_file { read write };
```

But I suppose there must be a cleaner way to fix this problem. Anyone?

Comment: Did you try to `restorecon /var/spool/postfix` after mounting?

Comment: Yes, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: output of lsblk, vgdisplay, lvdisplay, mount maybe?

Comment: Nothing strange there